# How to write update query to update two tables with SQL Data Source?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

Is it possible to update two tables using SQL Data Source and ASP.NET Grid View? I have the following SQL Query for the Select statement.

```
SELECT 
   tbl_user_login.ID, tbl_user_login.UserID, 
   tbl_user_login.Pass, tbl_user_login.Enabled, 
   tbl_user_login.Permission, tbl_user_login.Rank, 
   tbl_user_profile.ID AS Expr1, tbl_user_profile.FName,
   tbl_user_profile.LName, tbl_user_profile.Phone, 
   tbl_user_profile.Email1, tbl_user_profile.Email2 
FROM 
   tbl_user_login 
INNER JOIN 
   tbl_user_profile ON tbl_user_login.ID = tbl_user_profile.ID
```

But I've no idea how do I write the update and delete statement in SQL Data Source

**UPDATE**

So I wrote the store procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTwoTable 
(
    @ID int, 
    @UserID varchar(10), 
    @Pass varchar(50), 
    @Enabled int, 
    @Permission int,
    @Rank int,
    @FName varchar(50),
    @LName varchar(50),
    @Phone varchar(50),
    @Email1 varchar(50),
    @Email2 varchar(50)
) AS

BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE tbl_user_login SET UserID = @UserID, Pass = @Pass, Enabled = @Enabled, Permission = @Permission, Rank = @Rank WHERE ID = @ID

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
    RETURN
END

UPDATE tbl_user_profile SET FName = @FName, LName = @LName, Phone = @Phone, Email1 = @Email1, Email2 = @Email2 WHERE ID = @ID

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
    RETURN
END

COMMIT
```

But I get the `Procedure or function UpdateTwoTable has too many arguments specified.`

**UPDATE**

I followed this guide and now the problem is solved. Thanks to everyone who helped!

http://www.whitworth.org/2006/01/16/how-to-troubleshoot-procedure-or-function-has-too-many-arguments-specified-in-aspnet-20/

Below is my SQL Data Source.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT tbl_user_login.ID, tbl_user_login.UserID, tbl_user_login.Pass, tbl_user_login.Enabled, tbl_user_login.Permission, tbl_user_login.Rank, tbl_user_profile.ID AS Expr1, tbl_user_profile.FName,
tbl_user_profile.LName, tbl_user_profile.Phone, tbl_user_profile.Email1, tbl_user_profile.Email2 FROM tbl_user_login INNER JOIN tbl_user_profile ON tbl_user_login.ID = tbl_user_profile.ID" 
        UpdateCommand="UpdateTwoTable" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="Original_{0}">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserID"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Pass"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Enabled"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Permission"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Rank"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="FName"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="LName"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Phone"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Email1"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Email2"/>
        </UpdateParameters>        
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Please send me the solution. the above given link is not working. I have the same problem and not getting the solution.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004869/procedure-or-function-has-too-many-arguments-specified-when-you-using-sqldataso

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible. Here is how to do it in a safe way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateUser (@ID int, @Pass varchar(15), @Email varchar(75)) AS

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    UPDATE tbl_user_login SET Pass = @Pass WHERE ID = @ID

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
        RETURN
    END

    UPDATE tbl_user_profile SET Email1 = @Email WHERE ID = @ID

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
        RETURN
    END

COMMIT
```

In this way you don't need to be worried in case there is some error raised by any of the updates. Which means: If any of them will fail, the whole operation will be canceled and you will not have inconsistent data in your DB.

More about the use of `Transactions` here: https://web.archive.org/web/20210513004758/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/080305-1.shtml

The basic [DELETE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) is: `DELETE FROM <tablename> WHERE <condition>`

Comment: I wrote the store procedure and now I'm getting this error.

`Procedure or function UpdateTwoTable has too many arguments specified.`

Comment: @Ye: Check the number of `<UpdateParameters>` inside your GridView markup

Comment: @abatishchev Ermm. It matches isn't it? 11 parameters are passed to Store Procedure. Or did I miss something there?

Comment: @Ye: @Davis's stored proc accepts only 3: `@ID, @Pass, Email`

Comment: @abtishchev, No no. I've wrote my own stored proc. Please check the Update in the question.

Comment: Found the culprit finally. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROC UpdateUser
(
    @ID int
    ,@Pass varchar(15)
    ,@Email varchar(75)
   ) AS
BEGIN

Update
   tbl_user_login
Set
   Pass = @Pass
Where
   ID = @ID

Update
  tbl_user_profile
Set
  Email1 = @Email
Where
  ID = @ID

END
```

You can write multiple sql commands into a single sproc as I have above. Expand updates as needed. Deletes work the same way...

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server":
    SelectCommand="SELECT ... "
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE a; UPDATE b;"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM a; DELETE FROM b;" />
```

Doesn't it work?

Comment: @Ye: Yes, sure, that's just the beginning of each query. I just mentioned the general idea

Comment: I've tried and postback was completed without any error but data wasn't updated. I don't get any error. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ye: You can subscribe on events `RowUpdated` and `RowDeleted` and maybe find something useful. Do you use transactions?

Comment: Nope. I tried your suggestion first. Okay. I'll check these events.