# How to display Gridview with Joins using ASP.net with the Update command specified

Tags: asp.net, .net

How to display Gridview with Joins using ASP.net with the Update command specified,i tried with this code but still no use :(

`UPDATE WSR.dbo.tb_Project p1 SET p2.ClartiyID=@ClarityID,p2.Start_date=@start_date,p2.End_date=@End_date,p2.Planned_efforts=@Planned_efforts
WHERE (ProjectID=@ProjectID)` ?

i have two tables and how to update that through Joins ?
Wat table name should i mention in the Update **'table_name'** set **column_name** to update the record in both the tables ?

Answer (score 0):

[How to write update query to update two tables with SQL Data Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754869/how-to-write-update-query-to-update-two-tables-with-sql-data-source) has a set of full answers.