# How to parameterize the Update query in SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]

I am maintaining an old website, the code was pretty messy.

I want to use SqlDataSource to do the Updating, selecting, inserting functions.
I really **do not want to write the back-end code** by myself. (I actually have already written all code, but the old code is too messy to test and does not have comments so it makes me very hard to detect where bugs are, so I have discarded the back-end code and am using SqlDataSource)

**Instead, I'd like to use the UpdateCommand in SqlDataSource do to the update.**
Here is my Updating query:

```
UPDATE MedicareLocalAccounts SET Account=@Account and PWD=@PWD WHERE DivisionID=@DivisionID
```

The data source comes from 3 different tables.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gv_MediCareLocals" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="LUDivisionsUID" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
            EnablePersistedSelection="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="LUDivisionsUID" HeaderText="Division ID" ShowHeader="true"
                    SortExpression="LUDivisionsUID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Division" HeaderText="Medicare Local" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Division"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="States" HeaderText="State" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="States" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Account") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <input type="text" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" id="tbAccount" value='<%# Eval("Account") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PWD") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <input type="text" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" id="tbPassword" value='<%# Eval("PWD") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

So as you can see, I need to have the DivisionID parameterized as well, but the DivisionID field does not have an ID (not like the Account and Password).
So How can I write the where clause in order to find the DivisionID in the current row?

**Update:**
I have changed the DivisionID column to

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DivisionID" SortExpression="LUDivisionsUID" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDivisionID" Text='<%# Eval("LUDivisionsUID") %>'>' ></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

But I got an error after I clicked the Update button.

> Could not find control 'tbAccount' in ControlParameter 'Account'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find
>   control 'tbAccount' in ControlParameter 'Account'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Could not find control 'tbAccount' in
>   ControlParameter 'Account'.]
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ControlParameter.Evaluate(HttpContext
>   context, Control control) +2155166
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.UpdateValue(HttpContext context,
>   Control control) +50
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.UpdateValues(HttpContext
>   context, Control control) +101
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.GetValues(HttpContext
>   context, Control control) +36
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.InitializeParameters(DbCommand
>   command, ParameterCollection parameters, IDictionary exclusionList)
>   +257    System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteUpdate(IDictionary
>   keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues) +222
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary keys, IDictionary
>   values, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback
>   callback) +87
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleUpdate(GridViewRow row, Int32
>   rowIndex, Boolean causesValidation) +1210
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean
>   causesValidation, String validationGroup) +738
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs e) +89    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +37
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs e) +88    System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +37
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
>   +121    System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +156
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +9642898    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1724

As you can see from the code, I have already applied the property ClientIDMode="Static" on both GridView and columns.
I use Chrome to see the generated ids for the Account column and found the id=tbAccount, but the name="ctl00$PageTitlePlaceHolder$gv_MediCareLocals$ctl02$tbAccount"

I don't think the Sql UpdateParameter is going to use the name property anyway.

Comment: when you click on a single row for update then you need to find the value stored in "<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="LUDivisionsUID" HeaderText="Division ID" ShowHeader="true"                  SortExpression="LUDivisionsUID" />" for individual row and use that value and pass in update method.

Comment: get the value of HyperLinkField like "((HyperLink)gv_MediCareLocals.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0] ).Text" and use in update query.

Comment: @Rahul Hi, I think I didn't state it clearly enough, I do not want to use the back-end code instead, I'd like to use SqlDataSource and write the parameterized query to do the update.

Comment: Try to check that link what it's in vb http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-vb

Comment: @Rahul, hi thank you for your reply. The example uses 1 single table, but in my case, I use 3 tables. So I cannot really do the step "Specify columns from a table or view" as it's not a table,but 3 tables. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If u create a stored procedure then it will be easy.For that purpose visit this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754869/how-to-write-update-query-to-update-two-tables-with-sql-data-source)

Hope it works.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thank you for your reply. Now the problem is I cannot get the access of the textbox embedded in the GridView : Could not find control 'tbAccount' in ControlParameter 'Account'.

Comment: first tell me in which event u r finding your tbAccount textbox,,your textbox is in EditItemTemplate so you cannot find it on pageload etc etc, You may find this control when it will come into existance means when your grid view will open in edit mode.you may find it on "RowDataBound" or "RowDeleting" or "RowUpdating" or "RowUpdating" grid event.I hope you understand...plz tell me that where or in which event u r finding that textbox value or control.

Comment: string Account= ((HtmlInputText)row.FindControl("tbAccount")).Value; by using this line you may get text value.

Comment: I do not use back-end code as I said in my post. I use SqlDataSource, so I have let the parameter get the value from tbAccount. If you could read through my question, I think you will understand.