# Want to create a Grid View in asp.net c# with CRUD operations. Please give me INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, crud

```
SELECT * FROM Book_Master A FULL OUTER JOIN Publication_Master B ON A.P_Id=B.P_Id
```

Above given statement is the query for viewing the tables

Following are the tables (that are included in the query),

```
1.) Book_Master

B_Id (Primary Key) [Identity Column]
B_Title
B_Author
B_Price
B_Quantity
P_Id (Foreign Key, to link this table with Publication_Master)



2.) Publication_Master

P_Id (Primary Key, linked with P_Id of Book_Master) [Identity Column]
Publication
P_Contact
P_Email
```

P_Id in Book_Master is foreign key and in Publication_Master it is the primary key.
B_Id and P_Id are identity columns (hence autogenerated)

Please give me INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE queries to be put in Grid View Configuration wizard to make the grid view CRUD-ready. I am a newbie to programming and i have to complete my project of inventory management system of books.

Comment: @RussCam Actually the update value is to be obtained runtime so i don't know what to put in SET book_master.B_Title='' and i actually don't know how to write these queries

Answer (score 1):

Check this. Refer fig 7 & 8 especially.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-cs

But if you are using joins & want to update two tables, then refer this:

[How to write update query to update two tables with SQL Data Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754869/how-to-write-update-query-to-update-two-tables-with-sql-data-source)